# How can I get information from my database and stick it into a Bootstrap select list?

Tags: sql, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to find the number of records in a table, and put their names into a select list.

Currently, my code for the list looks like:

`<label for="sel1">Select Widget 1:</label>
<select class="form-control" id="sel1"></select>`

As you can see I have no idea how to do this, and don't know where to start either. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The following article may assist:
[Generating HTML from SQL Server Queries](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/generating-html-sql-server-queries/)
The articles also shows you how you can define classes for the generated HTML tags for styling purposes.